# How can I check if a server has ssl enable or not

Tags: ssl

Does anyone of you know, if and if so, how can I check, with my application code, if a server has ssl enabled or not?

Comment: Could you provide some info. about the environment in which your are writing this?

Comment: You can't. Servers don't have ssl, websites do.

Comment: @Kuzgun that is simply wrong! A server can support SSL/TLS connection on some arbitrary port for a non-HTTP protocol **without** necessarily using it to secure HTTP connections.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

["It's easier to ask forgiveness than permission"](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2003-May/203039.html)

For example, to read `stackoverflow.com` via SSL, don't ask whether `stackoverflow.com` supports it, just do it. In Python:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> urllib2.urlopen('https://stackoverflow.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error (10060, 'Operation timed out')>
>>> html = urllib2.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com').read()
>>> len(html)
146271
>>>
```

It shows that `stackoverflow.com` doesn't support SSL (2008).

---

**Update:** `stackoverflow.com` supports https now.

Answer (score 7):

**11 Years later...**

I ended up here, because I had the same question (within terminal).

I suppose the easiest solution would be to use [`s_client`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-s_client.html) of [`openssl`](https://www.openssl.org):

```sh
openssl s_client -quiet -connect google.com:443
```

if this returns an exit status of `0` (check using `echo "$?"`), the host supports SSL/TLS on given port (here `443`).

Comment: This will only return 0 if the port supports SSL *and* openssl was able to verify the server certificate. If you don't care whether the server certificate is valid, just whether there is an SSL server listening, add `2>&1 | grep -q '^depth'` to the above command line. I'd be happy to learn of a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: What do mean by "SSL server"? a server that can handle an SSL-Handshake and returns a certificate?

Comment: In my testing exit status other than 0 is also good if it is able to list the certificates :)

Comment: @Edza you're right!

Answer (score 6):

You don't specify a programming language, but you could do this from the command-line.

```
bash-3.2$ echo ^D | telnet www.google.com https
Trying 66.102.11.104...
Connected to www.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
bash-3.2$ echo ^D | telnet www.stackoverflow.com https
Trying 69.59.196.211...
telnet: connect to address 69.59.196.211: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

There you go... Google does, StackOverflow does not.

Comment: This just checks that port 443 is open, not if that port (or any other port) is speaking ssl.

Comment: @Emirikol. Yup. 12 years later this is not the answer I'd give. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58754527/78845 is better.

Answer (score 3):

This is a C# unit test to perform the detection without having to be on the right HTTPContext:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DetectSslSupport()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.someinsecuresite.com");
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                //some sites like stackoverflow will perform a service side redirect to the http site before the browser/request can throw an errror.
                Assert.IsTrue(response.ResponseUri.Scheme == "https");
            }
        }
        catch (WebException)//"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."}
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

not sure on your language of preference but here it is in c#

```
public bool IsSecureConnection()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection || 
           HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["HTTP_X_SSL_REQUEST"].Equals("1");
}
```

Please note this header is custom, but I think you get the idea.  I've seen folk simply query request for "https" and besides looking dirty it's probably reasonably acceptable, depends on your security model.

Or are you asking whether it's simply available at all?

I

Comment: Thx dove, I think that is in the server-side, I want to know in client-side how can I know if a server accepts SSL connections. (If I can somehow). I think I can do it with some exception handling, if I try to connect to the server with ssl enable and I get an exception, then the server (probably) doesn't have ssl enabled. But can I do it in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what protocol you're working with -- there are SSL versions of HTTP, IMAP, POP, etc.

Assuming it's HTTPS you're interested in, you could check to see if something is listening on port 443 on the server and go from there...

Comment: Yes, I thought on that too, but I think the port of the service depends on configuration of the server, am I right? Btw, I'm working with https and smtp, sorry.
And my language of preference is C#, but I accept any language as answer, if I got one :P. Thank to you both ;)

Comment: Yes, the port does depend on the configuration -- but if you're just trying random sites using HTTPS, that's going to be on port 443. 

If it

Answer (score 0):

If you're running PHP or ASP code on a server, the short answer is you don't.  You can attempt to make a socket connection to the non-ssl IP address, and see if you get a ssl certificate, and enumerate its Common Name and SubjectAlternativeNames, but in general, the simple answer is you don't.  A frequent (mis)configuration of apache is to listen on port 443 without a SSL certificate, so being able to make the connection is no guarantee that there's SSL there.  Not being able to make the connection could mean that your application does not have networking privileges.  Because setting up SSL is a pain, you know whether you have SSL or not, and that's a configuration decision.  It's like wondering how many children you have - you should know.

Answer (score 0):

Batch SSL/TLS testing given input file `http.parsed` in the form

```
10.31.11.5:443
10.31.11.25:443
10.31.11.37:55000
10.31.11.116:80
```

Using GNU parallel

```
parallel -j10 'curl -k https://{} 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null && echo https://{}' :::: http.parsed
```

we get output

```
https://10.31.11.5:443
https://10.31.11.25:443
https://10.31.11.37:55000
```